# c++ : check if it is a Number in class

Tags: c++

in this code I want to know if two numbers are Int Or String :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class calculate{
    private:
        bool checkNumbers(int num1, int num2){
            if(isdigit(num1) && isdigit(num2)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

public:
    void sum(int x, int y){
        bool chek=checkNumbers(x, y);
        if(chek==true){
            cout<< "yes it is Number"<< endl;
        }else{
            cout<< "Nope! String"<<endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    calculate calulate;
    calulate.sum(3, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

But after run code, I just see **Nope! String** , it mean it is string. who know what is wrong? 
I checked numbers with **isdigit** and I just sent two numbers

```
calulate.sum(3, 2);
```

but nothing!!
thanks

Comment: `isdigit(2)` is false. `isdigit('2')` is true. It's not clear to me what you are trying to do here, and how `isdigit`is relevant to that. Say, could you show an example where you **expect** your program to print `"Nope! String"`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I Just want to do a practice, it is a calculate with a class. for first numbers send from main to calculate.sum function , in this function I wanted to check inputs ( actualy in this code it is static but maybe I want to get numbers from user) from private function calculate.checkNumbers , show error if user send characters to program.

Comment: it was my mistake :    calulate.sum('3', '2');

Comment: @user2215032 -- What if the number of characters is more than one digit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with your usage of `std::isdigit(int)`

The function is meant to check if a `int` is equivalent to one of the 10 `char`-represented decimal digits, `0123456789`. However, this function is only true for `int` values of 48-57.

`int` is expected to be the integer value of a `char`. If you want it to resolve `true`, use 48-57, where `48` is `0`, `49` is `1`, etc...

Note that your function would naturally resolve to true if you passed it a `char` such as '3', like one commenter stated. This is because `char(3) == int(51)`.

eg:

```
isdigit('1'); // This is true, because '1' is a "char" digit
isdigit(49); // This is true

isdigit(1); // This is false
isdigit(60); // This is false
```

Answer (score 0):

`num1` and `num2` are interpreted as characters by [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). Typically this means [ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

And as an ASCII character 2 and 3 are control characters and not digits, which are in the range of '0' (0x30) to '9' (0x39)